# File upload Jax-RS using POSTMAN : HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, file-upload, jax-rs, postman, multipartform-data

I am getting javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type while implementing jersey file upload example as mentioned in below URL :

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

I am hitting my request from Chrome POSTMAN Client,

Here is the snapshot of my request from POSTMAN client :

[image]

here is my code :
            imports :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;
```

service:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFiles")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response<Boolean> uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    Response<Boolean> result = new  Response<Boolean>();

    String uploadedFileLocation = UPLOADED_FILE_PATH  + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    result.Success=true;
    result.Data=true;
    return result;

}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can any one please help me to know why I am getting this exception ,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether the suggestion I posted worked ?? If not, then don't modify the post silently, if you are modifying the content of the post, then let everyone know (who posted the answer for your last post)

Comment: Did you get any solution ??? If yes, then let us know, if no, then what's the issue you facing ???

Comment: not solved yet ,  am getting javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: So, you should have at least let us know, if you are keeping the post open. People may get same issue will struggle same.

Comment: 1) Your screenshot shows 200 OK. Does that mean it worked?
2) What does your server logs say? What does the stacktrace tell ?
3) If you do a network traffic capture what do you see?

Comment: @AhmedMano Do you even bother to accept the correct answer else post the correct answer ??????

Comment: till now i do not have a  correct answer yet !!

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot provided you are trying to access resource to upload file is

```
http://localhost:6002/MyProject/rest/internetRestApi/uploadFiles
```

But, as per your implementation (shared code), I don't see any resource available instead you have

```
@POST
@Path("/upload2")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
```

So, as per above, your resource should be available at

```
http://localhost:6002/MyProject/rest/upload2
```

**Note :** For the sake of understanding, you should follow exact code what tutorial said. Don't try to mix-up your stuff with what is mentioned in tutorial in first attempt. Otherwise, you will end-up like this.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem resolved: there was two methods listening to the same URL and same http method (GET, PUT, ...)